# How to add CSS tag to ruby on rail loop?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to indent an entire loop, the one below, so i am assuming I need to put a tag on the entire thing so that I can point to it in the CSS file. I just dont know what format I should put it in.

```
<% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>

       <div class="box">
         <b>Vendor:</b>
         <%= comment.commenter %><br>
         <b>Deal:</b>
         <%= comment.body %>
       </div>

    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `content_tag` as below to wrap content in a `div` with a class name.

```
<% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, class: 'box') do %>
    <b>Vendor:</b>
    <%= comment.commenter %><br>
    <b>Deal:</b>
    <%= comment.body %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign a css class or id to a link_to method you do the following:

```
<%= link_to "Link name", { :controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name' }, :class => 'box' -%>
```

The key part is seperating the :controller => and :action from the html using the curly brackets.

Comment: but I dont need a controller or action. The loop is working fine, I just dont know how to tag it.

Comment: so usually you tag a paragraph with like <p4></p4>. Then you can say p4 {"css commands go here'} in the css file to move it around and syle that. I am trying to find how to tag the entire loop to style it (in this case I am trying to indent it)

Comment: Wrap the code above in a div and put margin-left: 10px or a css class with margin-left on the div? Take a look at the rendered html if things get confusing